# How to upload file in relationship hasOn<->belongsTo Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

Can be possible to store a file uploaded to a related table?
*Scenario:* I have a `usres` table in database and another one `pictures`. **Users Model** have the following function

```
public function picture()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Picture::class);
    }
```

And the **Picture Model** have the following function.

```
public function user_picture()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

Is possible to store the picture in `pictures` database table `(id, user_id, img_path)` from the **UserCrudController** `store()` function?

Comment: Is Patient and User table different ?

Comment: I edited the correct fuontion. Yes they are different tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue with the following steps.
As per Laravel Backpack I added the input field in the Blade:

```
@include('crud::fields.upload', ['crud' => $crud, 'field' => ['name' => 'img1', 'label' => 'Image 1', 'type' => 'upload', 'upload'=> true, 'disk'=>'uploads', 'attributes' => ['id' => 'img1', 'capture' => 'user']]])
```

After this I added the function in the User Controller as follow:

```
$request->validate(['img1' => 'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:5120']);
$fileModel = new Picture;
      if($request->file()) {
           $fileName1 = time().'_'.$request->img1->getClientOriginalName();
           $filePath1 = $request->file('img1')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName1, 'public');
$fileModel->name = time().'_'.$request->img1->getClientOriginalName();
$fileModel->img1 = '/storage/' . $filePath1;
$fileModel->save();
}
```

With these lines of code I was able to store the related Picture with the User.

Thank you all for the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
      Picture::create([
       'user_id' => // get the user id from $request or auth()->user(),
       'img_path' => $request->file('image')->store('images', 'public'),
      ]);
      return // your view or something  else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say it is a registration form that need to insert an image. Instead of using the `Picture` model directly you can just do this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(...);

    $user = User::create(...);

    //It will ensure that the image belongs to the user.
    $user->picture()->create([
        'image_path' => $request->file('image')->store('images');
    ])
}
```